# Labels on a grouped and stacked bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, graphs

I'm struggling to get the labelling correct on a complex stacked and grouped bar chart. I want to label each group of bars with an ethnic group, and within each group of bars, I want to label the three individual bars 1st, 2nd and 3rd. Any suggestions on how to do this would be welcome.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \caption{Graph showing the percentage of births in different partnership 
scenarios to women, by generation and ethnic group, 1986-2014}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every axis/.style={
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
  x axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, 
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  tickwidth = 0pt,
  width=17cm,
  height=8cm,
    symbolic x coords={
     African,
      African and White,
      African Caribbean,
      African Caribbean and White,
      Indian,
      Pakistani,
      Bangladeshi,
      Asian and White,
        },
  bar width=6pt
  },
]

\begin{axis}[bar shift=-12pt, xticklabels={}]
\addplot coordinates
{(African,64) (African and White,64) (African Caribbean,48) (African 
Caribbean and White,47) (Indian, 98) (Pakistani, 98) (Bangladeshi, 99) 
(Asian and White, 84)};
\addplot coordinates
{(African,12) (African and White,19) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,22) (Indian,1) (Pakistani, 1) (Bangladeshi, 0) (Asian 
and White, 11)};
\addplot coordinates
{(African,24) (African and White,17) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,31) (Indian, 1) (Pakistani, 1) (Bangladeshi, 1) (Asian 
and White, 5)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,53) (African and White,28) (African Caribbean,38) (African 
Caribbean and White,34) (Indian, 92) (Pakistani, 93) (Bangladeshi, 91) 
(Asian and White, 69)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,18) (African and White,19) (African Caribbean,19) (African 
Caribbean and White,28) (Indian,4) (Pakistani, 3) (Bangladeshi, 5) (Asian 
and White, 20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,30) (African and White,53) (African Caribbean,43) (African 
Caribbean and White,38) (Indian, 4) (Pakistani, 4) (Bangladeshi, 4) (Asian 
and White, 11)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=12pt,xticklabels={}]
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,42) (African and White,25) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,29) (Indian,88) (Pakistani, 85) (Asian and White, 50)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,19) (African and White,27) (African Caribbean,20) (African 
Caribbean and White,27) (Indian, 5) (Pakistani, 6) (Asian and White, 26)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,39) (African and White,48) (African Caribbean,47) (African 
Caribbean and White,44) (Indian, 7) (Pakistani, 9) (Asian and White, 25)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2):

To get a single label per group, set `xtick distance=1`. For the labels below the bars, you could add a plot with zero-height bars, and use `nodes near coords={some text}` to add the label, along with `every node near coord/.style={below}` to move the label below the bar.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
 \caption{Graph showing the percentage of births in different partnership 
scenarios to women, by generation and ethnic group, 1986-2014}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every axis/.style={
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    x tick label style={
       % add some negative yshift to move ticklabels down
       yshift=-4mm,
       rotate=45,
       anchor=east},
  x axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, 
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  tickwidth = 0pt,
  width=15cm,
  height=8cm,
  % symbolic coords have numerical distance of 1
  % so with the following line you get a tick at every symbolic coord
  xtick distance=1,
  symbolic x coords={
     African,
      African and White,
      African Caribbean,
      African Caribbean and White,
      Indian,
      Pakistani,
      Bangladeshi,
      Asian and White,
        },
  bar width=6pt
  },
]

\pgfplotsset{
  % define a new style used for the plot used to add labels
  % 2 args means it takes two mandatory arguments, so must be used as
  % labelplot={first arg}{second arg}
  labelplot/.style 2 args={
     % forget plot means it doesn't affect cycle lists or legends
     forget plot,
     % #1 is first argument, the text used in the nodes near coords
     nodes near coords=#1,
     % #2 is second argument, a length that should be the same as the bar shift for the axis
     every node near coord/.style={below,font=\tiny,xshift=#2}
  }
}
\begin{axis}[bar shift=-12pt, xticklabels={}]
\addplot [labelplot={1st}{-12pt}] coordinates
{(African,0) (African and White,0) (African Caribbean,0) (African 
Caribbean and White,0) (Indian, 0) (Pakistani, 0) (Bangladeshi, 0) 
(Asian and White, 0)};

\addplot coordinates
{(African,64) (African and White,64) (African Caribbean,48) (African 
Caribbean and White,47) (Indian, 98) (Pakistani, 98) (Bangladeshi, 99) 
(Asian and White, 84)};
\addplot coordinates
{(African,12) (African and White,19) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,22) (Indian,1) (Pakistani, 1) (Bangladeshi, 0) (Asian 
and White, 11)};
\addplot coordinates
{(African,24) (African and White,17) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,31) (Indian, 1) (Pakistani, 1) (Bangladeshi, 1) (Asian 
and White, 5)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
\addplot [labelplot={2nd}{0pt}] coordinates
{(African,0) (African and White,0) (African Caribbean,0) (African 
Caribbean and White,0) (Indian, 0) (Pakistani, 0) (Bangladeshi, 0) 
(Asian and White, 0)};

\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,53) (African and White,28) (African Caribbean,38) (African 
Caribbean and White,34) (Indian, 92) (Pakistani, 93) (Bangladeshi, 91) 
(Asian and White, 69)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,18) (African and White,19) (African Caribbean,19) (African 
Caribbean and White,28) (Indian,4) (Pakistani, 3) (Bangladeshi, 5) (Asian 
and White, 20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,30) (African and White,53) (African Caribbean,43) (African 
Caribbean and White,38) (Indian, 4) (Pakistani, 4) (Bangladeshi, 4) (Asian 
and White, 11)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=12pt,xticklabels={}]
\addplot [labelplot={3rd}{12pt}] coordinates
{(African,0) (African and White,0) (African Caribbean,0) (African 
Caribbean and White,0) (Indian, 0) (Pakistani, 0) (Bangladeshi, 0) 
(Asian and White, 0)};

\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,42) (African and White,25) (African Caribbean,33) (African 
Caribbean and White,29) (Indian,88) (Pakistani, 85) (Asian and White, 50)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,19) (African and White,27) (African Caribbean,20) (African 
Caribbean and White,27) (Indian, 5) (Pakistani, 6) (Asian and White, 26)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(African,39) (African and White,48) (African Caribbean,47) (African 
Caribbean and White,44) (Indian, 7) (Pakistani, 9) (Asian and White, 25)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```